# Running GUI applications available in the remote CLI based server in a local CentOS based machine

Tags: linux, lan, remote, gui

I have two machines connected in LAN. One with CentOS with GUI support (say that's local to me) and other a CLI based server. I would like to run applications available in the remote CLI based server that needs a GUI environment to run properly, in my local GUI supported CentOS machine. Is that possible?

I'd be glad to reply for any clarification.

EDIT: I already have openssh installed in both the machine and both can ssh to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your other CentOS is probably still Linux based, not CLI based. Your remote server needs an SSH server, best openssh and your local computer needs an SSH client, best openssh. :-)

To pull a xterm from the remote host you can then do this on your local machine:

ssh -X remoteHost xterm

After you entered your password an xterm running on the remote host, but displayed in your local X will pop up.

Comment: Thanks for replying I'm sure the  remote CentOS server is not GUI based. So I need a way to provide it a GUI enviroment from a different machine i.e. the machine local to me with GUI support.

Comment: Futhermore, I already have openssh in each of the machines and they are working fine...

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with "GUI environment". Are you talking about libraries that are required by some software, or are you talking about an X server or something completely different?

Because if you just want to have the firefox running on your remote server drawing its window on your (local) X-server, ssh -X is what you want.

Comment: yes, I kind of figured it out finally, ssh -Y or ssh -X is the way. Thank you, you helped a lot.